# Custom email form in iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, uikit, email

Say I want to send email to my server, but I want the user to not see my address, or perhaps I want the subject to be preset. What if I want to email the value of a UISlider or other UI element without the user seeing the whole email view.  How can I do that?

Must I use an Apple class, or can I use my own UITextFields?

Comment: I rather doubt Apple will let you hide any emailed information from the user. They're very picky about protecting actual and perceived privacy of users. An email interface to a single server that sends hidden information would be perceived by users as a privacy threat regardless of your intentions. You will have to be very careful of the way you handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The benefit of the Apple class is that you get the email address of the user.  If you do not care about that, you can submit anything you want to your own server as POST data or by whatever means you wish.  The interface can look like mail but the functionality will be like a web form.

If you need the address of the user and do not want to ask for it, then you will have to reveal the destination email address.  You can specify a subject and body, but the user will be able to modify it.